# The images in the recently viewed widget are not displayed in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, widget, wysiwyg

I tried the widget in localhost is shown, not in live site
I checked the difference the Enable WYSIWYG Editor was disabled, I enabled it
it worked

The next day, I checked it; it wasn't working again, not sure what happened.

[image]

Comment: you must be getting the errors into your browser console. Can you share the same errors? and also check the logs.